# Implementation of LRU cache

Tags: c++, c++11, cache

What do you think of this implementation of an LRU cache? I'm trying to migrate to modern C++, so it would be fantastic if you could give me any tips here. I've heard it's not desired to use raw pointers, right? What about only internally, as in the example?

Also, since I can't return a `nullptr` value in the `get()` method, what is the best alternative for this? Default value as in the example?

```
#ifndef __LRU_HPP__
#define __LRU_HPP__
#include <map>
#include<iostream>
#include<assert.h>

template<class T>
struct Default {
  T value;
  Default():value(){}
};

template<class K, class V>
struct node {
  K key;
  V value;
  node<K,V>* next;
  node<K,V>* prev;
  explicit node(K key, V value);
};

template<class K, class V>
class lru {
private:
  node<K,V>* head;
  node<K,V>* tail;
  std::map<K,node<K,V>*> map;
  std::size_t capacity;
  void replace(node<K,V>*);
public:
  explicit lru(std::size_t);
  void put(K key, V value);
  V get(K key);
};

template<class K, class V>
inline node<K,V>::node(K key, V value) {
  this->key = key;
  this->value = value;
}

template<class K, class V>
inline lru<K,V>::lru(std::size_t capacity) {
  assert(capacity > 1);
  this->capacity = capacity;
  this->head = tail = nullptr;
}

template<class K, class V>
void lru<K,V>::put(K key, V value) {
  auto it = map.find(key);
  if (it != map.end()) {
    node<K,V>* temp = it->second;
    temp->value = value;
    replace(temp);
    return;
  }
  if(capacity == map.size()) {
    tail->prev->next = tail->next;
    node<K,V>* target = tail;
    map.erase(target->key);
    tail = tail->prev;
    delete tail;
  }
  node<K,V>* temp = new node<K,V>(key, value);
  temp->prev = nullptr;
  temp->next = head;
  if(head != nullptr)
    head->prev = temp;
  else
    tail = temp;
  head = temp;
  map.insert(std::pair<K,node<K,V>*> {key, temp});
}

template<class K, class V>
V lru<K,V>::get(K key) {
  auto it = map.find(key);
  if(it != map.end()) {
    replace(it->second);
    return it->second->value;
  }
  return Default<V>().value;
}

template<class K, class V>
void lru<K,V>::replace(node<K,V>* temp) {
  if (temp->prev != nullptr)
    temp->prev->next = temp->next;
  if (temp->next != nullptr)
    temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
  if (tail == temp)
    tail = temp->prev != nullptr ? temp->prev : temp;
  if (head != temp) {
    head->prev = temp;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
  }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Two underscores are reserved *anywhere* for the implementation. Your program technically has undefined behavior because of your include guard.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Namespace Usage

I'd put *all* of this into some namespace, so it won't accidentally collide with other usage of the names it defines.

I'd probably also work even a little harder to do something to hide your `node` and `Default` templates. For example, `node` doesn't need to be visible to the outside world, so it would probably be better off defined inside of `lru`.

#### Prefer Initialization to Assignment

A constructor like this:

```
template<class K, class V>
inline node<K, V>::node(K key, V value) {
    this->key = key;
    this->value = value;
}
```

...is typically better written something like this instead:

```
template <class K, class V>
inline node<K, V>::node(K key, V value)
    : key(key)
    , value(value)
{}
```

In some cases, you *must* us initialization (like this) instead of assignment. In this case, it's not mandatory, but I still consider it preferable.

#### Consider passing by reference

Passing your `key`s and `value`s by value generally requires copying. You might want to consider whether it's worth passing by reference instead. This generally accomplishes little (or nothing) if the type being passed is "small", but can improve speed substantially if the type is large.

#### Encapsulate knowledge of a type's internals in that type

Right now, your `lru` class "knows" (depends upon) the internals of the `node` class. I'd generally prefer if only `node` knew about its internals. For one possibility, you might pass a `next` and `prev` to the ctor, and let it put those values into the `node` itself:

```
template <class K, class V>
inline node<K, V>::node(K key, V value, node *prev = nullptr, node *next = nullptr)
    : key(key)
    , value(value)
    , prev(prev)
    , next(next)
{}
```

In this case, your code like this:

```
node<K, V>* temp = new node<K, V>(key, value);
temp->prev = nullptr;
temp->next = head;
```

...would become something like:

```
node<K, V> *temp = new node<K, V>(key, value, nullptr, head);
```

#### Consider other Data Structures

Although a doubly-linked list *does* work for the task at hand, it's often fairly wasteful, using a couple of pointers per node in addition to the data you actually care about storing.

I'd consider using a singly linked list instead. Although it may not immediately be obviously how you can do this, I'm reasonably certain you can.

#### Consider pre-allocating your storage

Given that the total maximum number of objects is fixed when you create the cache, I'd also consider pre-allocating storage for both the objects and the linked-list nodes when you create the cache. An allocator for a fixed-size set of fixed-size blocks can be *really* trivial, which can improve speed considerably over using a couple of allocations on the free store for every item you insert in the cache.

Comment: I am not sure I understand how a circular buffer may be of help here. An entire point is to not change the locations of the values, that is keep them consistent with the pointers in the map, while changing their order.

Comment: For the `node` constructor, I recommend passing by value, as we store the arguments: `node(K key, V value) : key{std::move(key)}, value{std::move(value)} {}`.  That works well with glvalue and rvalue arguments quite happily, and favours moving over copying.

Comment: @vnp: Hmmm...I'm not sure what I was thinking, but I think you're right.

Comment: Awesome review! Though I'm not sure how I can implement this with a singly linked list. The problem here is that I need to navigate back when I remove the last element. In my case, I can just use `tail = tail->prev`. Also, the idea of pre-allocating my storage sounds good, I should definitely add it.  +1

Answer (score 7):

## Header guards

Your code contains undefined behaviour since the underscores are reserved for the implementation:

> #### 17.6.4.3 Reserved names [reserved.names]
>
> The C++ standard library reserves the following kinds of names:
>
> - macros
> - global names
> - names with external linkage
>
> If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.
>
> […]
>
> #### 17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
>     letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

So rename `__LRU_HPP__` to `LEAST_RECENTLY_USED_HPP` or similar.

## `Default`

Instead of

```
return Default<V>().value;
```

use

```
return V{};
```

Unless you want to use `Default<V>` to provide specializations.

## Possible bug

I'm rather sure you meant `delete target`, not `delete tail`.

```
  if(capacity == map.size()) {
    tail->prev->next = tail->next;
    node<K,V>* target = tail;
    map.erase(target->key);
    tail = tail->prev;
    delete tail;                     // << ?
  }
```

Otherwise you end up with a deleted, but not nulled `tail`.

## Call-by-reference

Use `const &` for arguments if you're not going to change them afterwards.

Comment: Good points, thanks! I've updated my answer. +1

Answer (score 7):

- There is no reason for `node` to know the key.
- The node constructor shall make a completely created node, that is `prev` and `next` fields should be initialized as well (to `nullptr`).
- Member initializer lists are preferred to constructor bodies. For example,

  ```
      lru<K,V>::lru(std::size_t capacity)
          : capacity(capacity)
          , prev(nullptr)
          , next(nullptr) {
              assert(capacity > 1);
      }
  ```
- Returning a `Default<V>.value()` does not fit the purpose. At least it means that the client cannot `put` such a value. An idiomatic (i.e. STL) way is to make `get` to return an iterator, with failure being signaled by returning `end` iterator.
- The sequence in `put`:

  ```
  tail->prev->next = tail->next;
  ....
  tail = tail->prev;
  delete tail;
  ```

  is a definite bug, and has many grave consequences.

  Consider a rewrite:

  ```
  ....
  tail = tail->prev;
  delete tail->next;
  tail->next = nullptr;
  ```
- The reviewer immediately notices another "bug" in `put` - namely that the head is not updated - and it takes time and mental concentration to recall the `capacity > 1` assertion, which makes the bug immaterial. I strongly recommend to factor the tail removal into a function with the name which reflects this fact. I suggest `pop_back_unguarded` or something along those lines.
- I don't think `replace` reflects what the function actually does. `bump_up` perhaps?

Comment: I use `node->key` (for the last element in the list) to remove it from the `map` object.  I've decided to return `V {} ` as the default value. I think `iterator` should be used for sequences only, right? Though I'm not sure how it's done in C++. Nice review +1, thanks